# Getting wrong expiry_date_ms in in-app purchase

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase

I am getting expires_date_ms is less than today, while my Subscription is for 1 Month.

```
       if (Platform.OS === 'ios') 
        {
        try {

            console.log('In Checking')
            const availablePurchases = await 
             RNIap.getAvailablePurchases();
            console.log("Available Purchase", availablePurchases)
            const sortedAvailablePurchases = availablePurchases.sort(
                (a, b) => b.transactionDate - a.transactionDate
            );
            if (sortedAvailablePurchases.length > 0) {
                const latestAvailableReceipt = sortedAvailablePurchases[0].transactionReceipt;
                const isTestEnvironment = __DEV__;
                const decodeReceipt = await RNIap.validateReceiptIos({
                    'receipt-data': latestAvailableReceipt,
                    'password': ''
                }, isTestEnvironment);
                console.log('decodeReceipt',decodeReceipt)

                const { latest_receipt_info: latestReceiptInfo } = decodeReceipt;
                const isSubValid = !!latestReceiptInfo.find(receipt => {
                    const expirationInMilliseconds = Number(receipt.expires_date_ms);

                    const nowInMilliseconds = Date.now();
                    return expirationInMilliseconds > nowInMilliseconds;
                });
                return isSubValid
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Got an error while getting purchases", err);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I am using react-native-iap.
version : 3.3.9
RN version : 0.59.9

I need to check whether my subscription is Active or not.
but I am getting expiry date lesser then today.`enter code here`
So, it always gives me inactive.
Please guide me on this.

Comment: It could be a timezone thing between the `expires_date_ms` and `Date.now()`? Ideally you'd be checking this against a server timestamp instead of device time. There's a surprisingly high number of devices with incorrect system times - thanks Candy Crush :)